# Can I use a .pdf letterhead in Odoo 9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

We have a company letterhead document which we apply to all outgoing official documents. This is a .PDF document with a header and footer.

Is it possible to integrate this document to odoo v9 so it will be used or all our generated docs?

Answer (score 0):

yes can can have global header and footer for your company.

you need to go to the `settings >> companies` and edit company record. where you can find the "Report Configuration" tab. in that you can edit the RML header as you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Atul, Thanks for your answer. I went to odoo but can't find any tab or option called "companies" under the settings ! Just for information, i'm using the v9 of odoo. Thanks so much.